# How can I click on a list of item that is opened and closed by having/loosing focus on an ion input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

In Ionic Angular, I am asking the user to enter an ip in an ion-input.
To help the user, a list of item with previous searched ips appears  when he is entering text inside the ion-input. This list is shown thanks to a variable that is set to true when the focus is set on the ion input and set to false when the ion-input looses the focus.

I would like to set the ion-input value to the value of the item clicked. Unfortunately when I click on the item, the ion-input looses focus, the list hides and the click on the item is not taken into account.

I can fix that by having a "setTimeout" in my blur function but I would like to know if a proper solution exists while still behing able to hide the list when the input looses focus (for instance clicking somewhere else on the page).

### **Current solution**

- HTML

  ```
           <ion-item>
               <ion-label position="floating">Robot Manager IP</ion-label>
               <ion-input  
                   [(ngModel)]   ="rmIpBuf"
                   (ionBlur)     ="showBlur($event)"
                   (ionFocus)    ="onFocus('ip',$event)">    
               </ion-input>         
           </ion-item>

           <div *ngIf="isShowIpList === true">
               <ion-row *ngFor="let searchIp of searchedIps, let i = index">
                   <ion-col size=12 class="ion-text-center" >
                       <ion-item  button  (click)="addToInput('ip',searchIp,$event)">
                           <ion-text color='medium'>{{searchIp}}</ion-text>
                       </ion-item>
                   </ion-col>
               </ion-row>
           </div>
  ```
- .ts

  ```
  showBlur(ev) 
   {
       setTimeout(() => {
           this.isShowIpList = false
       }, 400);

      this.isShowIpList = false  
   }
  ```

'''

```
onFocus(paramInputType: string,ev:Event)
    {   
       this.isShowIpList   = true;
    }

addToInput(type:string, value,ev:Event)
{
   this.rmIpBuf = value;
}
```

'''

I also have a function to manage the searchList which is running properly. It's not important here.

If you know cleaner, better, smarter, faster or stronger solutions, please let me know :) !

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/saty932/ionic2-searchbar-suggestions-above-content

Comment: Thanks for your answer @NajamUsSaqib, unfortunately this is not what I am looking for. In my project I am currently able to propose the list but when my input looses focus, I want to hide the search list. Yet, I also want to be able to click on an item from the list, which I have done by adding a setTimeOut. Just wanted to know if something cleaner exists